# Laravel: validate an integer field that needs to be greater than another

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two fields that are optional only if both aren't present:

```
$rules = [
  'initial_page' => 'required_with:end_page|integer|min:1|digits_between: 1,5',
  'end_page' => 'required_with:initial_page|integer|min:2|digits_between:1,5'
];
```

Now, `end_page` needs to be greater than `initial_page`. How include this filter?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There is **no built-in validation** that would let you compare field values like that in **Laravel**, so you'll need to implement a **custom validator**, that will let you reuse validation where needed. Luckily, Laravel makes writing custom validator **really easy**.

Start with defining new validator in yor **AppServiceProvider**:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function boot()
  {
    Validator::extend('greater_than_field', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
      $min_field = $parameters[0];
      $data = $validator->getData();
      $min_value = $data[$min_field];
      return $value > $min_value;
    });   

    Validator::replacer('greater_than_field', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
      return str_replace(':field', $parameters[0], $message);
    });
  }
}
```

Now you can use your brand new validation rule in your **$rules**:

```
$rules = [
  'initial_page' => 'required_with:end_page|integer|min:1|digits_between: 1,5',
  'end_page' => 'required_with:initial_page|integer|greater_than_field:initial_page|digits_between:1,5'
];
```

You'll find more info about creating custom validators here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules. They are easy to define and can then be used everywhere you validate your data.

Comment: thanks, I implemented is as you said and tried to edit my `en/validation.php` with following message `"greater_than_field" => "Field \":attribute\" must be greater than \":field\".",` in `Custom Validation Language Lines` but I can't figure out with what to replace `:field`.

Comment: I updated the answer - you need to define replacer that will substitute message placeholders with correct values. I haven't tested that, I just took it from the docs http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Meanwhile I changed my form to use array syntax for field names like `category[id]` instead of just `id`. When I try to use `"category.secondnumber" => "greater_than_field:category.firstnumber"` I get error: `Undefined index: category.firstnumber`. Using this syntax with `after`  works so I guess the syntax is ok but validator is not complete. Thanks in advance. I'll implement replacer and report after I figure this problem out.

Comment: @Sliq, @4ndro1d: It works just fine in L5.2.  I made my own provider at `App\Providers\CustomValidationServiceProvider.php` and registered it to `config\app.php` as such: `App\Providers\CustomValidationServiceProvider::class,`  Otherwise, I just copied and pasted his answer into the `boot()` function and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Did anyone figure out the :field replacement part?  The code above does replace :field with my field name, but I want the "friendly" field name.  Even if the replacement field name is in the attributes array of validation.php, it still isn't used.

Comment: The validation replacer() message is typically just string replacement of $message. It could be something like `return str_replace('validation.greater_than_field', "$attribute must be greater than {$parameters[0]}", $message);`

You can do something fancier with your attribute names depending how you name them e.g. replace underscores with spaces. Of course, you can also override this default error message in your validation e.g. `'yourField.greater_than_field' => 'Something must be greater than something'`.

Comment: L5.7 - You now have the `gt` (and `lt`) form validation rules. So just add this rule: `'end_page' => 'required_with:initial_page|integer|gt:initial_page`.

Answer (score 74):

The question was asked in 2015 so most of the answers are also outdated now.

I want to give an answer that uses features provided by the Laravel team which is included in it's new version.

So as stated by @Sarpadoruk as of Laravel 5.6 Laravel added features in validation like
`gt`, `gte`, `lt` and `lte` which means:

- `gt` - greater than
- `gte` - greater than equal to
- `lt` - less than
- `lte` - less than equal to

So using `gt` you can check that your `end_page` should be greater than your `initial_page` and your task becomes very easy now:

```
$rules = [
  'initial_page' => 'required_with:end_page|integer|min:1|digits_between: 1,5',
  'end_page' => 'required_with:initial_page|integer|gt:initial_page|digits_between:1,5'
];
```

Comment: Your answer saying "outdated now in 2019" is outdated now in 2023 xD

Comment: @DavidsKanal bcs it was written in 2019, just updated.

Comment: Yesyes it was a joke xD

Answer (score 22):

For Laravel 5.4 it will be:

```
$rules = ['end_page'=>'min:'.(int)$request->initial_page]
```

Comment: As @sobhan suggested, `$this` may work but it's important to mention it depends strongly on the context. For example `$this` is available as a `Request` instance in form requests. For controllers, you'll have to access the request directly as stated in previous answers and comments.

Comment: Is it really alright to **re-inject a part of untrusted input** like this? This looks like a potential invitation to all kinds of vulnerabilities...

Comment: @user1643723 That's right. Adding `(int)` before request can make it safe. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

As of Laravel 5.6 [`gt`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-gt), `gte`, `lt` and `lte` rules are added.

Answer (score 15):

I think you can try something like this,

```
$init_page = Input::get('initial_page');

$rules = [
    'initial_page' => 'required_with:end_page|integer|min:1|digits_between: 1,5',
    'end_page' => 'required_with:initial_page|integer|min:'. ($init_page+1) .'|digits_between:1,5'
];
```

Comment: my rules is inside my model class and i dont wanna access this variable in there, however thanks :-)

Answer (score 5):

use gt = greater than: value|field

use gte = greater than equal: value|field

use lt = less than: value|field

use lte = less than equal: value|field

In your case it is:

```
gt:initial_page
```

And the result will be:

```
$rules = array(
      'initial_page' => 'required_with:end_page|numeric|min:1|digits_between: 1,5',
      'end_page' => 'required_with:initial_page|numeric|gt:initial_page|min:2|digits_between:1,5'
      );
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just define `$min_number = $min + 1` number and use validator `min:$min_number`, example:

```
$min = intval($data['min_number']) + 1;

return ['max_number'  => 'required|numeric|min:'.$min];
```

And you can then return custom error message to explain the error to user.

Answer (score 1):

If you're maintaining a project on Laravel 5.2 then the following should backport the current gt rule for you:

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function boot()
  {
    Validator::extend('gt', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
      $min_field = $parameters[0];
      $data = $validator->getData();
      $min_value = $data[$min_field];
      return $value > $min_value;
    });   

    Validator::replacer('gt', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
      return sprintf('%s must be greater than %s', $attribute, $parameters[0]);
    });
  }
}
```

You can then use it as per the current documentation:

```php
$rules = [
  'end_page' => 'gt:initial_page'
];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 9.x you can use `gt:field`

For example:

```
$rules = [
  'initial_page' => 'required_with:end_page|integer|min:1|digits_between: 1,5',
  'end_page'     => 'required_with:initial_page|gt:initial_page'
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-gt