# How can I make multiples of thousands validation on laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.4, required

My validation on laravel like this :

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    ...
    'amount' => 'required|integer|min:20000',
]);
```

I want the value of amount is multiples of thousands

So the value that can be input only multiples of thousands

For example :  25000, 50000, 151000, 200000 etc

The examples of inputs that are not multiples of thousands : 25500, 50500, 151500, 200500 etc

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can take the modulo of that numberת implement this logic using a custom validation rule:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules

something like this should do:

```
  Validator::extend('mod1000', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return $value % 1000 == 0;
  });
```

Comment: Yes I know that. But how do I make it in laravel validation. If laravel validation, it needs to be added here : `'amount' => 'required|integer|min:20000',`. But I'm still confused how can I add it

Comment: @SuccessMan see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036882/laravel-validate-a-integer-field-that-needs-to-be-greater-than-another might help you

Comment: @SuccessMan change your validation like this `'amount' => 'required|integer|min:20000|mod1000'`.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me, There exist error : `Method [validateMod1000] does not exist.`

Comment: @SuccessMan you have to first define it with the extend method like I showed

Comment: @raam86, Whether it defined in the service provider?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression for such validation like this:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    ...
    'amount' => 'required|integer|regex:/^[1-9]+[0-9]*000$/',
]);
```

Last three zero's in the expression are for thousands. First number should be other than zero and any numbers between them is a perfect validation for your case.

hope you understand.

Comment: There exist error : `preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found`

Comment: @SuccessMan you might need to escape it with \

Comment: @SuccessMan I'd forgot to add `/` over there. I've updated.

Comment: @SagarGautam shouldn't that be `\\`?

Comment: @Wreigh I've just forgot the syntax of regex