# Laravel Validation = integer value must > 2 if checkbox is checked

Tags: laravel

How to validate the value of a `textbox` which must be greater than **2** if a checkbox is checked.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='chk'>
<input type='text' name='txt'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work for me:

```
'txt' => 'required_if:chk,1|integer|between:2,99
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel validation rules you have to check whether `checkbox` is `checked` or not. If its is `checked` then you have to validate the `textbox` with:

```
$rules = ['txt'=>'min:2']
```

Refere this link
[Laravel: validate a integer field that needs to be greater than another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036882/laravel-validate-a-integer-field-that-needs-to-be-greater-than-another)

Hope this helps you!