# Laravel validating. One field must be greater than another

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to do some laravel validation.

I need to ensure that the field max rent is always great than min rent and to proivded a message letting the user know.

Here is my validation code in my controller

```
$this->validate($request, [
        "county" => "required",
        "town" => "required",
        "type" => "required",
        "min-bedrooms" => "required",
        "max-bedrooms" => "required",
        "min-bathrooms" => "required",
        "max-bathrooms" => "required",
        "min-rent" => "required|max4",
        "max-rent" => "required|max4",
      ]);
```

I'm not using a seperate rules method. This is within the controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: validate an integer field that needs to be greater than another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036882/laravel-validate-an-integer-field-that-needs-to-be-greater-than-another)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Similar, but not a duplicate

Comment: What is different to your situtation?

Comment: How is mine a duplicate of the above.

Comment: Why not use a [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests) and handle the validations there?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Custom Validation Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules).

## 1. Create the Rule class

```php
php artisan make:rule RentRule
```

## 2. Insert your logic

**App\Rules\RentRule**

```php
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class RentRule implements Rule
{
    protected  $min_rent;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @param $min_rent
     */
    public function __construct($min_rent)
    {
        // Here we are passing the min-rent value to use it in the validation.
        $this->min_rent = $min_rent;         
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // This is where you define the condition to be checked.
        return $value > $this->min_rent;         
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        // Customize the error message
        return 'The maximum rent value must be greater than the minimum rent value.'; 
    }
}
```

## 3. Use it

```php
use App\Rules\RentRule;

// ...

$this->validate($request, [
        "county" => "required",
        "town" => "required",
        "type" => "required",
        "min-bedrooms" => "required",
        "max-bedrooms" => "required",
        "min-bathrooms" => "required",
        "max-bathrooms" => "required",
        "min-rent" => "required|max4",
        "max-rent" => ["required", new RentRule($request->get('min-rent')],
      ]);
```

---

## Side note

I suggest you to use [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation) classes to extract the validation logic from the controller and decouple your code. This will let you have classes that has just one responsability making it easier to test and cleaner to read.

Comment: Nice and complete answer. Thanks.

Comment: I want to achieve this using only FormRequest. is that possible?

Comment: @JunaidQadirShekhanzai of course it can be done. The only difference is the way to pass pass values to your custom Rules- Instead of: `"max_rent" => ["required", new RentRule($request->get('min_rent')],` you should do this:        `"max_rent" => ["required", new RentRule($this->min_rent)],`. If you have trouble with this let me know.

Answer (score -3):

We can use parameters from the request as a part of the validation rule. This may use in a situation like one field must be greater than another field. The following code is an example of checking `max-rent` should be greater than `min-rent.` In this case the validation rule `numeric` important we are checking numbers, otherwise it will check the number of characters.

```
$request->validate([
    "min-rent" => "required|numeric|max:9999",
    "max-rent" => "required|numeric|min:{$request->input('min-rent')}|max:99999",
]);
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-size (same rules are applied to min). "For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters". It doesn't refer to the value of field min-rent.

Comment: Yes I did check it, because it sounds like a very simple solution. But it didn't work. It might seem to work on the first glance, because in that case, the length of the string min-rent is used for min. See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1042 and https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1449

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it