# Laravel validation of one field being greater than or equal to another field not working

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.8.26 and am trying to validate that one field is greater than or equal to another field.

Here's my code:

```
'amountMin' => 'required|numeric|gte:0',
'amountMax' => 'required|numeric|gte:amountMin',
```

the value for `amountMin` is 5000 and the value for `amountMax` is 40000.

when my code runs I get the message that `amountMax` must be greater than or equal to `amountMin`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372543/laravel-validating-one-field-must-be-greater-than-another) StackOverflow post that says in order to do this you have to create a custom validation rule, but according to the way I understand Laravel validators to work my code should work. Am I wrong, do I need to create a custom validation rule to ensure `amountMax` is greater than or equal to `amountMin` or do I just need to adjust my code a bit to get it to work?

As always a correct, clearly explained answer will be marked as accepted answer and upvoted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there:

```
'amountMin' => 'required_with:amountMax|numeric|gte:0',
'amountMax' => 'required_with:amountMin|numeric|gte:amountMin',
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but sadly this does not work for me.

Comment: Try `min:0` instead of `gte:0`.

Comment: updated my code to this:
`'amountMin' => 'required_with:amountMax|numeric|min:0',
 'amountMax' => 'required_with:amountMin|numeric|gte:amountMin',`
and it still doesn't work. Is this what you were trying to indicate?

Comment: Yes. What version of Laravel?

Comment: 5.8.26, posted in my OP