# Validate user balance Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

On table users I have column `balance`.

I have method on controller:

```
public function orderPayout(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'sum' => 'required|integer|min:20|max:15000'
    ]);
}
```

This method take a sum for order Payout.

How I can validate balance user `Auth::user()->balance` if > 20 and < 15000 how on sum. ?

Comment: Can you be more clear? What you want to do with user balance?

Comment: @vivek_23 I want validate him fo betweenr [20, 15000], how validate sum

Comment: `sum` is validated. You want to check if user's balance lies between 20 and 15000, but what is the relation between `sum` and user balance?

Comment: `sum` is field of the form, this is input, where user write sum for payout. Yes I want check is users balance lies between 20 and 15000

Comment: `if(Auth::user()->balance >= 20 && Auth::user()->balance <= 15000)`

Comment: @vivek_23  know this :) But I want with validate do this..

Comment: This validates the user balance. In `else`, you can write the logic for what if balance is not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `between` validation rule.

```
'sum' => 'required|between:20,15000'
```

UPDATE:

```
public function orderPayout(Request $request) {
    $request->merge(['sum' => $request->user()->balance]);

    $request->validate([
        'sum' => 'required|between:20,15000'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: this is field on form, but not is balance of user

Comment: then, you have to get the user in question from your request.


if it is current logged in user, 


you can modify the request to get currently logged in user and merge the balance as an input.

Comment: But this ($request->merge) is not overwrite current sum?

Comment: yes it will merge the current form, what did you want to achieve actually?! is it to check the sum of the order is within user balance budget?!

Comment: Yea, if user have enough balance amount, then do payout

Comment: use this rule instead

`'sum' => 'required|integer|min:20|max:' . $request->user()->balance`

Comment: But if `$request->user()->balance` = 0 ? Then max: will be 0 ? :))

Comment: lol, yeah you're right, or you can use custom validator 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036882/laravel-validate-an-integer-field-that-needs-to-be-greater-than-another