# Laravel: Validate min and max value based on input fields

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am trying to add validation for the min and max values. Both these values are coming from input fields.

I want to validate that max value (`max_price`) should always be greater than min value (`min_price`).

I am working on the Laravel 5.7

```php
$validator = validator($request->all(),[
  'min_price' => 'required|min:1"',
  'max_price' => 'required|numeric|min:min_price',
]);
```

Comment: What's the question? ;-)

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036882/laravel-validate-an-integer-field-that-needs-to-be-greater-than-another

Comment: ^ There *is* such a validator however: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-gt

Answer (score 9):

You can use the code below

```
$validator=validator($request->all(),[
    'min_price'=>'required|min:1',
    'max_price' => 'required|gt:min_price'
]);
```

References

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-gt
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-min

Comment: Thnx for the solution and refrence. It worked fyn. There is just 1 issue. If we keep min_price field empty then it crashes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the rule `gt` (Greather than) that expect the number of another field as first argument:

```
'min_price'=>'required|numeric|min:30',
'max_price'=>'required|numeric|gt:min_price'
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've changed and why? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Comment: because gte match value greater than or equal and you say that you get value greater than that i have changed from gte to gt now you can get get value greater than

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the answer itself.