# Laravel Validation amount array of fields not work

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-validation

I have created rule validation as follow :

```
$rules = [
  'items.*.qty' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1'],
  'items.*.ordered_qty' => ['required','numeric','min:1']
]
$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

here i need to validate that each `ordered_qty` should be greater than `qty` I have tried the below way but it doesn't work for me

```
$rules = [
  'items.*.qty' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1','max:items.*.ordered_qty'],
  'items.*.ordered_qty' => ['required','numeric','min:1']
]
$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

i tried custom validation also but i could not able to getting the value of other field

```
$rules = [
  'items.*.qty' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1',function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if ($value > ordered_qty) {
                $fail(':attribute qty is invalid!');
            }
        }],
  'items.*.ordered_qty' => ['required','numeric','min:1']
]
```

It validate wrong. How can i do the comparision on array of objects among their attributes

Comment: write the custom validation rules for this ?

Comment: yes i tried that also but how can i getting the value of other field inside the custom validation function

Comment: Possible of duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036882/laravel-validate-an-integer-field-that-needs-to-be-greater-than-another

Comment: @Sethu the mention question is releated to single filed validation but my question is array of fields

Comment: try like this 'required|soft_delete:pim_attribute_fields,'.$attribute_id,

Comment: @kmgkumar this not regarding the embed field this is how to embed dynamic current field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the max on qty but max suspect a value while you are trying to validate it with the input of another field. I think you need to use lte, see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-lte