# How to validate against multiple values in Laravel's FormRequest?

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm passing two fields to my API `max_duration` and `min_duration`, and I'm using Laravel's FormRequest to perform validaiton. Here's my **RecommendationRequest.php** class:

```
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "max_duration" => ["integer", new ValidateMaxDuration],
            "min_duration" => ["integer", new ValidateMinDuration]
        ];
    }

}
```

here's my `ValidateMaxDuration.php` Rule that I want to validate that the `max_duration` value is higher than the `min_duration` value. How can I do this?

```
class ValidateMaxDuration implements Rule
{
    private $minDuration;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // $this->minDuration = $minDuration;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // logic done here to validate max value
        // return $value[0] < $value[1] ? false : true; 
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return "Max duration must be a higher value than min duration.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: validate an integer field that needs to be greater than another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036882/laravel-validate-an-integer-field-that-needs-to-be-greater-than-another)

Comment: @N69S right thanks