# Making sure one input field is greater than the other in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a form that has a `start_odo` and an `end_odo` for vehicle mileage tracking that user needs to enter. The problem is that currently, they can enter a `start_odo` that is higher than the `end_odo` and that results in a negative difference. Is any way to ensure that the `end_odo` will always have to be higher?

Being fairly new to Laravel, I read about the `gt:field` but I am not quite sure how to interpret it in my code as it looks different. Could someone nudge me in the right direction.

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // $energy = new Maintenance;
    $energy = new VehicleLog();
    $energy->start_odo = $request->input('start_odo');
    $energy->end_odo = $request->input('end_odo');
    $energy->km = $request->input('end_odo') - $request->input('start_odo');
    $energy->save();

    return redirect('/vmaintenance')->with('success', 'data added');
}
```

my view:

```
<div class="mb-3" style="float:left;" style="margin-left: 200px;">
    <label for="recipient-name" style="width: 7em"class="col-form-label">Start ODO</label>
    <input type="number"style="width: 7em" name="start_odo" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" min="0" required>
</div>
        
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">End ODO</label>
    <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="end_odo" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" min="0" required>
</div>
```

The validation code I saw while reading:

```
$request->validate([ 
    'detail' => 'gt:20', 
]);
```

Comment: can you post the validation code

Comment: you need to validate your inputs before saving to database.

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai I edited the question to show it. Is there any way to implement it in mine?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon How would I do that?

Comment: use  FormRequest classes validations for like operations

Comment: @dılosürücü Forgive me for asking silly questions, how can I?

Comment: have you read the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation)? it has an excellent description to do validation.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I have but I cannot figure out how to incorporate it into my code.

Comment: Please try searching before posting a new question.  Note the accepted answer is old, scroll down for simpler, more up-to-date solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036882/laravel-validate-an-integer-field-that-needs-to-be-greater-than-another

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: validate an integer field that needs to be greater than another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036882/laravel-validate-an-integer-field-that-needs-to-be-greater-than-another)

Comment: Your style-conventions should be revised:  
`class="mb-3" style="float:left;" style="margin-left: 200px;"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to figure out yourself how to write code. there are lots of answers and tutorials out there regarding this. however i am adding this answer to get you started.
in your store method, validate the data before saving to database.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // validation logic
    $request->validate([
        'start_odo' => 'required',
        'end_odo' => 'required|gt:start_odo',
    ]);

    // if validation passes this will now store values in db
    $energy = new VehicleLog();
    $energy->start_odo = $request->input('start_odo');
    $energy->end_odo = $request->input('end_odo');
    $energy->km = $request->input('end_odo') - $request->input('start_odo');
    $energy->save();

    return redirect('/vmaintenance')->with('success', 'data added');
}
```

now explore the doc how to show validation errors in the form and other ways to validate data.

Comment: Thank you! it does not add the record if its below the `start_odo`. Just need to work on the error message now.

Comment: laravel has a quite well doc. you can find a lot of tutorials on this as well. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As @zahidhasanemon had already indicated. You can achieve it with customs rules. First step would be to define the new validation rule in your AppServiceProvider.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function boot()
  {
    Validator::extend('greater_than_field', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
      $min_field = $parameters[0];
      $data = $validator->getData();
      $min_value = $data[$min_field];
      return $value > $min_value;
    });   

    Validator::replacer('greater_than_field', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
      return str_replace(':field', $parameters[0], $message);
    });
  }
}
```

Then you can use this new validation rule in your controller like that:

```
$request->validate([ 
    // other validations rules
    'end_odo' => 'required|greater_than_field:start_odo', 
]);
```

Comment: There is [a built-in `gt` rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-gt) which does this already, no need for custom rules.

Comment: Ah cool! Good to know. Thanks @Don'tPanic  I will updated my answear or deleted.